# Cannot get zedgraph to work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, zedgraph

I've tried to make a method, which insert some numbers in a zedgraph. But it won't work.
This is my code:

```
        string title = "Contemporary Quality";
        string xaxis = "Amount";
        string yaxis = "Percent";
        zedGraphControl3.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
        zedGraphControl3.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl3.GraphPane;
        myPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
        myPane.CurveList.Clear();
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = xaxis;
        myPane.Title.Text = title;
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = yaxis;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = false;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinGrace = -0.5;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 16;
        myPane.BarSettings.Type = BarType.PercentStack;
        double[] x = new double[] { zg1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min, zg1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max };
        double[] y = new double[] { 20, 20 };
        ZedGraph.LineItem lineItem = new ZedGraph.LineItem("cursorY1", x, y, Color.Black, ZedGraph.SymbolType.None);
        lineItem.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
        lineItem.IsSelectable = false;
        lineItem.Label.IsVisible = false; // hides the cursor in the legend
        zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Add(lineItem);

        y = new double[] { 40, 40 };
        lineItem = new ZedGraph.LineItem("cursorY2", x, y, Color.Black, ZedGraph.SymbolType.None);
        lineItem.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
        lineItem.IsSelectable = false;
        lineItem.Label.IsVisible = false; // hides the cursor in the legend
        zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Add(lineItem);
        y = new double[] { 60, 60 };
        lineItem = new ZedGraph.LineItem("cursorY3", x, y, Color.Black, ZedGraph.SymbolType.None);
        lineItem.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
        lineItem.IsSelectable = false;
        lineItem.Label.IsVisible = false; // hides the cursor in the legend
        zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Add(lineItem);
        y = new double[] { 80, 80 };
        lineItem = new ZedGraph.LineItem("cursorY4", x, y, Color.Black, ZedGraph.SymbolType.None);
        lineItem.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
        lineItem.IsSelectable = false;
        lineItem.Label.IsVisible = false; // hides the cursor in the legend
        zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Add(lineItem);

        PointPairList PPLa = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLb = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLc = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLd = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList PPLf = new PointPairList();

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int f = 0;

        List<string> newlistString = new List<string>();
        DateTime end = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
        DateTime start = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        newlistString = ctrscan.AnalyzeOldScans(start, end);

        for (int h = 0; h <= (newlistString.Count - 1); h++)
        {
            if (newlistString[h].Equals("A"))
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }
            if (newlistString[h].Equals("B"))
            {
                b = b + 1;
            }

            if (newlistString[h].Equals("C"))
            {
                c = c + 1;
            }
            if (newlistString[h].Equals("D"))
            {
                d = d + 1;
            }
            if (newlistString[h].Equals("F"))
            {
                f = f + 1;
            }
            double aa = Convert.ToDouble(a);
            double bb = Convert.ToDouble(b);
            double cc = Convert.ToDouble(c);
            double dd = Convert.ToDouble(d);
            double ff = Convert.ToDouble(f);
            PPLa.Add(h,aa);
            PPLa.Add(h, bb);
            PPLa.Add(h, cc);
            PPLa.Add(h, dd);
            PPLa.Add(h, ff);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d+" "+f);
        BarItem myBara = myPane.AddBar("Quality A", PPLa, Color.Red);
        BarItem myBarb = myPane.AddBar("Quality B", PPLb, Color.Blue);
        BarItem myBarc = myPane.AddBar("Quality C", PPLc, Color.Gray);
        BarItem myBard = myPane.AddBar("Quality D", PPLd, Color.Black);
        BarItem myBarf = myPane.AddBar("Quality F", PPLf, Color.Pink);


        zedGraphControl3.AxisChange();
        zg1.AxisChange();
```

The output from the "consolewriteline" is: 0 15 56 4 9. And therefor I expect at least 4 bars on the graph. But nothing happens. Hope anyone knows..
Thanks.

Comment: I've also tried to move the "plla.add" methods outside of the loop, and that didn't work either.

Comment: you only fill PPLa with values, that needs a change, PPLb and so on might be filled also

Comment: OMG, that was so lame. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    PPLa.Add(h,aa);
    PPLa.Add(h, bb);
    PPLa.Add(h, cc);
    PPLa.Add(h, dd);
    PPLa.Add(h, ff);
```

needs to be:

```
    PPLa.Add(h,aa);
    PPLb.Add(h, bb);
    PPLc.Add(h, cc);
    PPLd.Add(h, dd);
    PPLe.Add(h, ff);
```

i hope this will work for you

Comment: which one doesnt show? zg1 or zg3? also. take a look at PPLa-e to check if this is filled right. if not you need to look at your filling part of code. and another also, make your myPane.Barsetting to normal to see if there is anything working